# How to handle cookies with the string "#HttpOnly" in the domain of a cookie

Tags: cookies

I am programmatically reading a file which is in Netscape cookie jar format

http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5

When I parse the file I find cookies with the following domain

```
"#HttpOnly_.foo.bar.com"
"#HttpOnly_foo.bar.com"
```

My question is that if I'm making a connection to the site foo.bar.com should I include these cookies or not?

I am little surprised to see "#HttpOnly" in the domain name. I thought the domain of the cookies should always be either "foo.bar.com" or ".foo.bar.com"